# ¿Cuando se puede decir que un chisme es un "chisme de lavadero"?

Tags: méxico, coloquialismos

Quiero saber que es lo que hace a un chisme que sea "de lavadero"

La RAE da estas acepciones:
**chisme.**
(Quizá del lat. cimex, chinche).
**1.** m. Noticia verdadera o falsa, o comentario con que generalmente se pretende indisponer a unas personas con otras o se murmura de alguna.
**2.** m. coloq. Baratija o trasto pequeño.
~ de vecindad.
**1.** m. coloq. El que versa sobre algo de poca importancia.

¿Que un chisme sea "de lavadero" cambia la acepción de la palabra chisme?
¿Es lo mismo un "chisme de lavadero" que un "chisme de vecindad"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sí, es lo mismo. También se puede usar "chisme de callejón". 
Chisme de lavadero proviene de que en algunas "vecindades" (aplica también para "callejones" en otros países), se solía contar con un solo "lavadero" (lugar donde se lava la ropa, una fuente de agua con suficiente espacio para tal fin, sin ser una lavandería propiamente) para todos los habitantes.

Answer (score 0):

Así es, viene de que anteriormente los lavaderos eran punto de reunión de las amas de casa, y mientras pasaban horas tallando la ropa platicaban entre ellas y se ponían al tanto de las actividades de los demás. Así pues, los lavaderos eran el sitio donde circulaban todo tipo de rumores. La expresión "chismes de lavadero" tiene una cierta connotación peyorativa y algo clasista, por ejemplo, si le quieres hablar mal de una persona, tu interlocutor te podría responder que "no le interesan los chismes de lavadero". O lo puede usar para descalificar el rumor "No creo que engañe a su esposo, de seguro no es más que un chisme de lavadero".